# Why GridView Filter is not working with me?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have gridview that has a filter expression.

It is not working at all, I mean data is not filtered.

I used a very simple basic expression, still not working

I thought maybe someone can helpe me figure out what the problem is?

````
<asp:GridView ID="grdTags" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnSelectedIndexChanged="grdTags_SelectedIndexChanged" 
    AllowPaging="false" AllowSorting="True" OnSelectedIndexChanging="grdTags_SelectedIndexChanging"
        DataSourceID="dsTagsDetailsSelect"
    FilterExpression="Occurrence > 5"> 
    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField HeaderText="&gt;&gt;" SelectText="&gt;&gt;" ShowSelectButton="True">
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="Gainsboro" />
        </asp:CommandField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Occurrence" HeaderText="Count" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Occurrence" >
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="Gainsboro" />
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Tag" HeaderText="Tag" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Tag" >
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="Gainsboro" />
        </asp:BoundField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsTagsDetailsSelect" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DeepMedConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="TagsDetailsSelect" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="hfRepID" Name="RepID" PropertyName="Value" Type="Int64" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Tag" Type="String" DefaultValue="*" />
    </SelectParameters>
    <FilterParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="cbx1" Name="p1" PropertyName="Checked" Type="String" />
    </FilterParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem is that you've put the FilterExpression on the GridView, when you should have put it on the SqlDataSource because [FilterExpression is a property of a SqlDataSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.filterexpression?view=netframework-4.8); FilterExpression is not a property of the [ASPNET GridView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview?view=netframework-4.8)

If this isn't a standard ASP GridView and does have a FilterExpression property, please link to its documentation